# Spliting Fullname into Surname and Forename

Tags: string, oracle

I want to split the following name as Surname and Forename in Oracle. Please note that a full name can have 2, 3, 4 or more words. Last name is the surname. So basically I want the first word from the right as Surname and the remaining string on the left is the Forename.

Examples:

1. "Mary Edward Alex Tario" - Here Surname should be "Tario" and Forename should be "Mary Edward Alex".
2. "John Travolta" - Here Surname is "Travolta" and Forename is "John".

Comment: Is the surname **always** one word? What if the full name is [Dick Van Dyke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Van_Dyke) (first name: "Dick") or [Helena Bonham Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helena_Bonham_Carter) (first name: "Helena")?

Comment: See also: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names)

Comment: I forgot to ask yesterday: what have you tried so far, and why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do this with `regexp_substr()`, it is probably simpler with the basic string functions:

```
select substr(name, 1, length(name) - instr(reverse(name), ' ')) as firstname,
       substr(name, length(name) - instr(reverse(name), ' ') + 1) as lastname
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thank you for a quick response. This worked . Thanks very much for your help :)